# How to get total column using ReactJS?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, get, axios, nan

I'am newbie on ReactJs, I want when I select the product name the price will be displayed, after that I put the Quantity and the total column will be displayed the result of Quantity*Price.
I try to display the price, but the problem the total column always displayed NaN. As you can see the code  below :

```
class AjouterFacture extends Component {
  constructor(props) {
    super(props);
    this.state = {

      rowData: [],

      Produits: [],
      Quantite: "",
      Prix: [],

      id: 0
    };
    this.handleSubmit = this.handleSubmit.bind(this);
    this.handleRowDelete = this.handleRowDelete.bind(this);
    this.handleRowAdd = this.handleRowAdd.bind(this);
    this.handleQuantiteChange = this.handleQuantiteChange.bind(this);
    this.handleselectprdtChange = this.handleselectprdtChange.bind(this);
    this.PrixDisplay = this.PrixDisplay.bind(this);
    this.TotalDisplay = this.TotalDisplay.bind(this);

  }
  componentWillReceiveProps(nextProps) {
    console.log("nextProps", nextProps);
  }
  componentDidMount() {
    axios({
      method: "get",
      url: "/app/getNomprod/",
      withCredentials: true,
    }).then(response => {
      if (response && response.data) {
        this.setState({
          Produits: response.data
        });
      }
    }).catch(error => console.log(error));

  }
  handleQuantiteChange(index, value) {
    const rowDataCopy = this.state.rowData.slice(0);
    rowDataCopy[index] = Object.assign({}, rowDataCopy[index], {
      Quantite: parseInt(value, 10)
    });
    this.setState({
      rowData: rowDataCopy
    });
  }
  handleselectprdtChange(index, value) {
    const rowDataCopy = this.state.rowData.slice(0);
    rowDataCopy[index] = Object.assign({}, rowDataCopy[index], {
      selectprdt: value
    });
    this.setState({
      rowData: rowDataCopy,
    });
  }

  render() {

    let {
      Clients
    } = this.state.Clients;
    var Cd = {
      pointerEvents: 'none'
    }
    let {
      Produits
    } = this.state;
    let {
      rowData
    } = this.state.rowData;
    let {
      Prix
    } = this.state.Prix;

    return (<div className="animated fadeIn">



 <h6>  <Label ><strong>Veuillez ajouter au moins un produit :  </strong></Label></h6>
        <Table responsive style={items} >
        <thead style={back}>
                  <tr>
                    <th>PRODUIT</th>
                    <th>QUANTITE</th>
                    <th>PRIX UNITAIRE</th>
                    <th>TOTAL</th>
                    <th></th>
                  </tr>
                  </thead>
                  <tbody>
                {this.state.rowData.map((data, index) => (
              <tr key={index} id={index}>
                <td>
                  {" "}  <Input type="select" name="selectedcl" id="selectcl"
                          placeholder="Veuillez sélectionner un produit"  value={data.selectprdt}
                    onChange={(e) => this.handleselectprdtChange(index, e.target.value)} >
           <option  key={-1} hidden>Choisisr un produit</option>


                     {  this.state.Produits.map((pdt, i) => 
                     <option key={i}>{pdt.Nomp}</option>
                     )} 

                      </Input>
                    </td>
                    <td><Input type="number" 
                          value={data.Quantite || 0} onChange={(e) => this.handleQuantiteChange(index, e.target.value)}/></td>
                    <td>
                     {  this.state.Prix.map((pr, k) => 
                     <p key={k} >{pr.PrixV} </p>
                     )} 

                        </td>
                <td  > 
                     <p key={index} className='pa2 mr2 f6'>{(data.Quantite || 0) * (parseInt(this.PrixDisplay(data.selectprdt)))}  </p>
                    </td>
                    <td>
                     <Button onClick={(e) => this.handleRowDelete(index)} active style={center}  size="sm" color="danger" className="btn-pill" aria-pressed="true">Effacer</Button>
      </td>{" "}
              </tr>
            ))}  
                  <tr>parseInt(
            <td/>
            <td/>
            <td/>
            <td/>
            <td><Button onClick={this.handleRowAdd} active style={center}  size="sm" color="info" className="btn-pill" aria-pressed="true">Ajouter une ligne</Button></td>
          </tr>
        </tbody>

        <tfoot>
          <tr>

            <th></th>

            <th></th>
          </tr>
</tfoot>
        </Table>

        </div>
);
  }
  PrixDisplay(selectprdt) {
    return axios.get("/app/getPrixprod/" + selectprdt).then(response => {
     if (response && response.data) {
        this.setState({
          Prix: response.data
        });
      }
    }).catch(error => {
      console.error(error);

    });
  }
  TotalDisplay(){


   return   this.state.Prix.map(pr =>
      parseInt(pr.PrixV));



  }

  handleRowDelete(row) {
    const rowDataCopy = this.state.rowData.slice(0);
    rowDataCopy.splice(row, 1);
    this.setState({
      rowData: rowDataCopy
    });
  }
  handleRowAdd() {
    let id = this.state.id;
    id = id++;
    const rowDataCopy = this.state.rowData.slice(0);
    rowDataCopy.push({
      selectprdt: "",
      Quantite: 0,
      Prix: 0
    });
    this.setState({
      rowData: rowDataCopy,
      id: id
    });
  }
}
export default AjouterFacture;
```

How can I display it ?

Comment: what you see here if you do `console.log(rowTotals)` ? I think `(row.Quantite * row.PrixV)` evalutes to `NaN` for some entries.

Comment: @ArupRakshit No, I edit the code, my issue is about this column :   `<td  > 
                     <p key={index} className='pa2 mr2 f6'>{(data.Quantite || 0) * (parseInt(this.PrixDisplay(data.selectprdt)))}  </p>
                    </td>`

Answer (score 1):

Bonjour Melissa !

I think you try to display a value with :

```
{(data.Quantite || 0) * (parseInt(this.PrixDisplay(data.selectprdt)))}
```

But I see `PrixDisplay` is a function that do not return integer or everything else than a Promise. So, in fact you seems to multiply `data.Quantite` with a `parseInt` of a `NaN` value try snippet below.

In your case I think you need to :

1. Declare in your state `displayedPrice : 0` (if `Prix` isn't the same thing)
2. Use `{(data.Quantite || 0) * (this.state.displayedPrice || 0)}`
3. Call your `PrixDisplay(data.selectprdt)` function who already set `Prix` in your state. When you need it.
4. And voilà ! When `axios` get the response, the `setState` function will update `Prix` and `displayedPrice` and that will trigger a re-render of your component who display the good value.

Bien à toi.

```js
console.log(2 * parseInt(Promise.resolve()))
```

Comment: Thank you @S.C, you mean I edit this.setState to  `this.setState({
          Prix: response.data,
          displayedPrice : 0
        });` and `(this.state.displayedPrice || 0)`  ?

Comment: Yep, Like that, you'll be able to trigger `this.PrixDisplay()` function whenever you want (on user action, product / quantity change etc...)

Comment: when I edit my code as you post,The price column is not displayed and the column Total display to 0, but when I change that by `{(data.Quantite || 0) * (parseInt(this.PrixDisplay(data.selectprdt)))}` the price will be displayed and the column display to NaN and I need both of them will be displayed..

Answer (score 1):

According to your DOM, it appears that you're expecting the function `PrixDisplay` to return a value.

```
<td > <p key={index} className='pa2 mr2 f6'>{(data.Quantite || 0) * (parseInt(this.PrixDisplay(data.selectprdt)))} </p> </td>
```

However your function only sets state i.e., it does not return anything. Additionally, you will need to set the right value in the price array with the new value like so:

```
PrixDisplay(index, selectprdt) {
 const priceArray = this.state.Prix;
 return axios.get("/app/getPrixprod/" + selectprdt).then(response => {
  if (response && response.data) {
    priceArray[index] = response.data;
    this.setState({ //<---- You're doing just a setState and not returning anything.
      Prix: priceArray
    });
  }
 }).catch(error => {
  console.error(error);

 });
}
```

What you can do instead is

```
{(data.Quantite || 0) * (parseInt(this.state.Prix[index].PrixV || 0))}
```

Comment: when I edit my code by `{(data.Quantite || 0) * (parseInt(this.state.Prix[index] || 0))}` The price column is not displayed and the column Total display to 0, but when I change that by `{(data.Quantite || 0) * (parseInt(this.PrixDisplay(data.selectprdt)))}` the price will be displayed and the column display to NaN and I need both of them will be displayed..

Comment: I have updated my answer. I believe you will need to do `parseInt(this.state.Prix[index].PrixV || 0))`

Comment: It 's still the same issue @dkulkarni Can I share the git file ?

Comment: Yup I can take a look

Comment: https://gist.github.com/IchrakMansour/94e1672245be090a45555e4190cf5e8a     I want when I select the product name its price will be displayed, my issue is the price is displayed the same for others row and the issue of total.This is : https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51912740/having-the-same-value-of-price-and-total-column-using-reactjs

Comment: Okay so the problem is you're resetting `Prix` in your state. What you should be doing is updating only the specified index in the array. Sort of like how you've done in `handleQuantiteChange`. Pass an `index` as another parameter to something like `PrixDisplay(index, selectprdt)`. I have updated my answer too.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/178298/discussion-between-melissa-and-dkulkarni).